# Trouble with checkboxes and selects interaction on click and on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox, onclick

I have a form where a user can specify hotel-accomodations for a biking event. The options are:

1) stay the night before (+50 euro)

2) have dinner the night before (+20 euro)

He also has the possibility to book a room at the hotel for up to 6 "non-bikers". If the user has checked either one of the above options, the added costs must also apply to any non-bikers he has added - but only if they are adults (older than 12), which is determined by dropdowns.

Example: Base hotel-cost = 100 euro. User checks the "night before" checkbox, total price is now 150. If he also checks the "dinner before" checkbox, total price is now 170. If he then adds two non-bikers, the total hotel-cost for those two becomes 340 (2 x 170).

I have this working kind of, but run into trouble when
1) either of the checkboxes are repeatedly checked/unchecked
2) user changes the value of the dropdown(s) more than once

I'm also aware that my jQuery code is painfully repetitive...

Html (simplified):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="want_pre_stay" value="1" id="want_pre_stay"> Stay the night before <strong id="price_pre_stay">50</strong> 
<input type="checkbox" name="want_pre_dinner" value="1" id="want_pre_dinner"> Dinner night before   <strong id="price_pre_dinner">20</strong>
Total personal accomodation (before non-bikers are added): <strong id="price_hotel"></strong>

<select name="nf_geboortejr[]" class="form-control input-sm" id="nf-0">
<option value="1934">1934</option>...<option value="2014">2014</option>
```

There's 6 of these selects, all of them initially hidden, except for the first one (the id names go up to "nf-5"). Selects "nf-1" to "nf-5", when shown, can be hidden again, at which point the total cost for non-bikers should reflect this...

Total non bikers is shown here:

```
Total accomodation for non-bikers: <strong id="nf-total"></strong>
```

JavaScript:

```
var price_hotel = 100;
var price_pre_stay = 50;
var price_pre_dinner = 20;
var end_total = 100;

var want_pre_stay = 0;
var want_pre_dinner = 0;

var y = 2014;

// on document.ready

$('#price_pre_stay').hide();
$('#price_pre_dinner').hide();

$('input[name=want_pre_stay]').on('click', function(){
$('#price_pre_stay').toggle();
if($(this).prop('checked')){
    want_pre_stay = 1;
    price_hotel = price_hotel + price_pre_stay;
    end_total = end_total + price_pre_stay;
    $('#price_hotel').number(price_hotel, 2, ',', ' ' ); //uses jQuery plugin
    $('#end_total').number(end_total, 2, ',', ' ' ); //uses jQuery plugin
}
if(!$(this).prop('checked')){
    want_pre_stay = 0;
    price_hotel = price_hotel - price_pre_stay;
    end_total = end_total - price_pre_stay;
    $('#price_hotel').number(price_hotel, 2, ',', ' ' );
    $('#end_total').number(end_total, 2, ',', ' ' );
}
});

// I have exactly the same code for $('input[name=want_pre_dinner]')

// #nf-0 = first "non-biker" dropdown
$('#nf-0').on('change', function(){
select_val = $(this).val();
age = y - select_val;   
if(age > 12){
    nf_total = nf_total + price_hotel;
    end_total = end_total + price_hotel;
}   
if(want_pre_stay == 1 && age > 12){
    nf_total = nf_total + price_pre_stay;
    end_total = end_total + price_pre_stay;
}
if(want_pre_dinner == 1 && age > 12){
    nf_total = nf_total + price_pre_dinner;
    end_total = end_total + price_pre_dinner;
}

$('#nf-total').number(nf_total, 2, ',', ' ' );
$('#end_total').number(end_total, 2, ',', ' ' );
});
// I have another 5 of these, up to $nf-5...
```

Can this be made to work in a way that's unaffected by how many times either checkboxes are checked/unchecked, and regardless of how many times the select values are changed?

Thanks in advance for any replies...

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle.net, please?

Comment: Okay, give me a minute...

Comment: Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5b0wmdf9/1/ (dropdown doesn't work for some reason, but you get the idea...)

Comment: You did not define nf_total - so what do I have to click and change to see an issue? Is it not just that you need to -= the de-clicks?

Comment: New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5b0wmdf9/3/ here drop down doesn't  work properly either though.

Comment: Your code needs to be thrown out and rewritten. On each click and change have ONE calculation. Instead of setting some boolean on click of the checkboxes, simply look at the all checkboxes and selects every time.

Comment: I realise the code is bad, that's the reason I'm asking the question. I am trying to rationalise it, but that's where I'm hitting the brick wall...

Comment: That doesn't seem to work at all? -EDIT: you had one }) too many... Am looking into this, thanks.

Comment: Looking at the calc() function in your above fiddle, I have no clue as to how to extend it so it takes in account the state of the checkboxes without resorting once again to on.click()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/b6kj6msz/)

```js
var price_hotel = 100;
var price_pre_stay = 50;
var price_pre_dinner = 20;

function calc() {
    var nfTot = 0,end_total = 0;
    $(".nf").each(function () { // each non-biker
        nfTot += calcNF(this);
    });
    $('#nf_total').text(nfTot);

    end_total = nfTot + // non-bikers
        price_hotel + // the person filling in the form
        ($('input[name=want_pre_stay]').is(":checked") ? price_pre_stay : 0) + 
        ($('input[name=want_pre_dinner]').is(":checked") ? price_pre_dinner : 0);

    $('#end_total').text(end_total);

}

function calcNF(nf) {
    var nfValue= nf.value;
    if (nfValue=="") return 0; // nothing selected here

    var age = new Date().getFullYear() - nfValue; // as of now

    if (age < 12) return 0;
    return price_hotel + 
        ($('input[name=want_pre_stay]').is(":checked") ? price_pre_stay : 0) + 
        ($('input[name=want_pre_dinne]').is(":checked") ? price_pre_dinner : 0);
}

$(function () {

    $('#price_pre_stay').hide();
    $('#price_pre_dinner').hide();
    $('#price_hotel').text(price_hotel);

    $('input[name=want_pre_stay]').on('click', function () {
        $('#price_pre_stay').toggle(this.checked);
        calc();
    });
    $('input[name=want_pre_dinner]').on('click', function () {
        $('#price_pre_dinner').toggle(this.checked);
        calc();
    });

    $('.nf').on('change', function () {
        calc();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="want_pre_stay" value="1" id="want_pre_stay">Stay the night before <strong id="price_pre_stay">50</strong> 
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="want_pre_dinner" value="1" id="want_pre_dinner">Dinner night before <strong id="price_pre_dinner">20</strong>
</p>
<p>Total personal accomodation (before non-bikers are added): <strong id="price_hotel"></strong>
</p>
<p>Non biker age:
    <select name="nf_geboortejr[]" id="nf-0" class="nf">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="1934">1934</option>
        <option value="1935">1935</option>
        <option value="1934">1936</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>Total accomodation for non-bikers: <strong id="nf-total"></strong>
</p>
<p>End total: <strong id="end_total"></strong>
```